# Can I use a regular (non-DBT) Python library within a DBT project?

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I'm trying to use a Python library within my DBT/Snowflake project, but the Python library has no dbt_project.yml file as it is not a DBT project itself. According to [DBT documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/packages) (and the error messages I receive when trying to install with `dbt deps`), any packages installed need to have a dbt_project.yml file at the top level. Is there really no way for me to use a library that isn't a DBT package specifically? Is there a way to import and use it locally?

Answer (score 0):

As a dbt package, no.

That said, dbt 1.3.0 supports Python models on Snowflake (Snowpark), so depending on whether Snowpark supports that Python library and your use case, you may be able to.